# eratic behaviour of select option in form

Tags: html, css

I have a form with following code.But it does not appear in web page as per the code there is one extra element in the web page.click For web page [image].when I check it on the inspect in browser developer mode I found this extra element click for Inspect element [image]Kindly help me to identify the mistake. My code is given below

```
<body>              
    <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:50px;">Online Stationery Management System (OSMS) </h1>
    <div class="login-box">
    <h1 >Login</h1>
    <form  name="signin" method="post">
    <div class="select2">
    <i class="fas fa-user-lock" style="color:black; padding:5px;">&nbsp;Role</i>
    <select name="role" id="role" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="user">USER</option>
    <option value="rec">Recommending Officer</option>
    <option value="store">Store</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-user" style="color:black"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uin" autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-lock" style="color:black"></i>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
 
  <input type="button" class="btn1" value="Forget Password" style="width:65%;margin-right:5px;">
  <input type="submit" class="btn" name="signin"value="Sign in" style="width:30%">
</div>
</form>
```

My css code for the file is

```
.select2 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 4px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.select2 option{
    width: 26px;
    background-color: none ;
    border: none;
    background: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
   float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  white-sapce: no-wrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background-color: none;
}
.select2 select{
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.select2::after {
  !content: 'Select Role';
  font-family: 'material icons';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: You haven't even mentioned what extra element? Please add such details in the ques.

Comment: @TusharShahi  if you clcik on the inspect element picture .There is one element  select wrapper in the code whereas it is not in the code.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party library? Also, add the previous comment in your question.

Comment: @TusharShahi no

Comment: @TusharShahi what do you mean by 'add the previous comment in your question'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Select2 js library. Maybe by mistake. It is overriding the default select to custom elements.

Comment: I am not using any Select2 js library

Comment: it seems like you do bro.. can you send a live link?